# Wrap groups of links with a div? (PHP is an option)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a dynamically generated number of links that I would like to put automatically into divs in groups of three. Is there any way to easily do this with jQuery?

The purpose is so that jQuery cycle could be used to cycle through these divs.

I was thinking of how it could also be done with PHP with a counter which would output an opening div and a closing div after three links, but it would never meet the condition to close the div if there were, for example, 5 links: a group of 3 and 2.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/RkzVy/

```js
$("a+a+a").wrapAll('<div class="testDiv"></div>');
```

```css
.testDiv {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google Link</a>
```

Comment: are the links dynamically generated or already on the page?

Comment: @Chad They are generated dynamically by wordpress.

Comment: How are they grouped? ID? Within a parent div? Class? Name?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3181731 A nice jQuery plugin to do exactly that. Hope you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/RkzVy/1/

```
var holder;

$("a").each(function(index, elem){
    if(index%3==0){
        holder=$("<div class='testDiv'></div>").appendTo("body");
    }

    holder.append(this);
});
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much for the prompt response!